# call AWS Elasticsearch Service API with cURL --aws-sigv4

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, curl, aws-signature

when I execute

```sh
curl --request GET "https://${ES_DOMAIN_ENDPOINT}/my_index_pattern-*/my_type/_mapping" \
--user $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
--aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:ap-southeast-2:es"
```

where `$ES_DOMAIN_ENDPOINT` is my AWS Elasticsearch endpoint, I'm getting the following response:

> {"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}

I'm confident that my `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are correct.

However, when I send the same postman request with the AWS Authentication and the parameters above, the response is coming through. I compared the verbose output of both requests and they have very minor differences, such as timestamps and signature.

I'm wondering, what is wrong with the `--aws-sigv4` config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens due to the`*` character in the path. There is a bug report in curl repository to fix this issue https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/7559.

Meanwhile, to mitigate the error you should either remove a `*` from the path or build curl from the branch https://github.com/outscale-mgo/curl-appimage/tree/http_aws_sigv4_encoding.